# How do composite indexes work and under what circumstances will they fail?

Tags: mysql, indexing

When building the index, I have some questions about the composite indexes.

Here is my SHOW CREATE TABLE

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sys_alarm`  (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_code` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr_value` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
  PRIMARY KEY (`alarm_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `search`(`dept_id`, `device_code`, `attr_name`, `create_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 16610 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

When I execute the following statement, the result I get confused me：

```sql
EXPLAIN
select a.alarm_id, a.dept_id, a.device_code, a.type, a.attr_name, a.attr_value, a.content, a.create_time
FROM sys_alarm a
WHERE a.dept_id = 214 
and a.create_time > "2021-11-06 15:00:17"

EXPLAIN
select a.alarm_id, a.dept_id, a.device_code, a.type, a.attr_name, a.attr_value, a.content, a.create_time
FROM sys_alarm a
WHERE a.create_time > "2021-11-06 15:00:17"
and a.dept_id = 214
```

and it result:

```
id  select_type table  partitions   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref    rows  filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      a       null        ref     search          search  9       const   1    33.33 Using index condition
```

I read this sentence on the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the SELECT statements shown here

so,why does the composite indexes still work? Only after I remove the `dept_id` query condition, the index will fail.What are the conditions for the composite indexes failure?

Comment: It is used as index for `a.dept_id = 214` and not as index but as more compact table version for `a.create_time > "2021-11-06 15:00:17"`.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your answers. I don't quite understand what you mean. This means that only `dept_id` takes effect as an index, and then other conditions do not hit the index. For example, if multiple conditions hit one of them, the index reading that hits will make the table range more compact. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Server firstly reads the index and finds the rows with `a.dept_id = 214`. In index. Then it takes these index records, extracts `create_time` from them and test these values against `a.create_time > "2021-11-06 15:00:17"`. The PK values for index records which matches both conditions are obtained. And pay attention - server have not read the table body yet! Now found PK values are used for to extract the table rows from the table body - only now the server reads the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will only use the "leftmost prefix" means that it will only use the `dept_id` portion of your index as it cannot skip to `create_time`. This is illustrated by the fact that `key_len` is 9 in the EXPLAIN output. I am a little confused as I would expect it to be 8 (the byte length of your BIGINT). There's a hole in my understanding here. Hopefully someone will explain this in the comments.

If you run your `EXPLAIN` with and without the `create_time` condition you should see the same result -

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT `a`.`alarm_id`, `a`.`dept_id`, `a`.`device_code`, `a`.`type`, `a`.`attr_name`, `a`.`attr_value`, `a`.`content`, `a`.`create_time`
FROM `sys_alarm` `a`
WHERE `a`.`dept_id` = 214;

EXPLAIN SELECT `a`.`alarm_id`, `a`.`dept_id`, `a`.`device_code`, `a`.`type`, `a`.`attr_name`, `a`.`attr_value`, `a`.`content`, `a`.`create_time`
FROM `sys_alarm` `a`
WHERE `a`.`dept_id` = 214
AND `a`.`create_time` > '2021-11-06 15:00:17';
```

| # id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | ref | search | search | 9 | const | 402 | 100.00 |  |

If you modify your query to add a condition for `device_code` you should see the `key_len` size change to 332, I'll come back to this later on.

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT `a`.`alarm_id`, `a`.`dept_id`, `a`.`device_code`, `a`.`type`, `a`.`attr_name`, `a`.`attr_value`, `a`.`content`, `a`.`create_time`
FROM `sys_alarm` `a`
WHERE `a`.`dept_id` = 214
AND `a`.`device_code` = 'ABCDE';
```

| # id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | ref | search | search | 332 | const | const | 1 | 100.00 |  |

And add `attr_name` -

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT `a`.`alarm_id`, `a`.`dept_id`, `a`.`device_code`, `a`.`type`, `a`.`attr_name`, `a`.`attr_value`, `a`.`content`, `a`.`create_time`
FROM `sys_alarm` `a`
WHERE `a`.`dept_id` = 214
AND `a`.`device_code` = 'ABCDE'
AND `a`.`attr_name` = 'dsgf';
```

| # id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | ref | search | search | 535 | const | const | const | 1 | 100.00 |  |

And finally adding back `create_time` -

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT `a`.`alarm_id`, `a`.`dept_id`, `a`.`device_code`, `a`.`type`, `a`.`attr_name`, `a`.`attr_value`, `a`.`content`, `a`.`create_time`
FROM `sys_alarm` `a`
WHERE `a`.`dept_id` = 214
AND `a`.`device_code` = 'ABCDE'
AND `a`.`attr_name` = 'dsgf'
AND `a`.`create_time` > '2021-11-06 15:00:17';
```

| # id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | range | search | search | 539 |  | 1 | 100.00 | Using index condition |

Now coming back to the `key_len` change from 9 to 332.  When only using the `dept_id` it is just the BIGINT. As soon as you add `device_code` it jumps to 332.  I am not 100% sure why 332 but it is something along the lines of - 80 (varchar length) * 4 (bytes per char due to multibyte charset) = 320.

The use of `ROW_FORMAT = Compact` would suggest that you are conscious of data size yet you are using a BIGINT (8 bytes) to store `dept_id`. Do you really need 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 departments?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I now know more about index. As for the field setting of dept_id, as you can see, I don’t know much about the database, so I use bigint to set the primary key of all tables (this is indeed a lazy behavior). And row_format = compact is It is used by default, so I don't understand the detailed principles, and I am still learning it. Thank you again for your answers and the questions you pointed out.

Comment: @cliash Make sure you also read Rick James' answer below and his linked article, which will really help further your understanding of indices. The usual default row format is DYNAMIC but it is configurable.

Comment: @cliash - `ROW FORMAT` is not worth worrying about to start with.  Just use the default.  Understanding indexes is the main lesson for a beginner to learn; and it is too complex to learn in one sitting.

Answer (score 0):

The order of clauses in `WHERE` does not matter.  The order of columns in an `INDEX` does matter.

Both of your queries and the first two by nnichols would benefit from `INDEX(dept_id, create_time)` *in that order*.

- `dept_id` is tested by `=`, so it should come first.
- `create_time` is tested by a 'range', so it should be last.

I discuss more details in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

nnichols goes on to have multiple `=` clauses, plus a `>` test.  The columns tested with `=` should come first in a composite `INDEX`, in any order, then followed by `create_time`.

Key_len and cardinality do *not* matter in the choice of how to arrange the columns in an index.

I agree that `BIGINT` is *rarely* needed.  `BIGINT NOT NULL` shows up in Explain as 8; `BIGINT NULL` shows up as 9.  That is, the mysterious 1 is because of being `NULLable`.  (It is not a big deal, just confusing.)  Meanwhile, a `DATETIME` will show up as 9 or 10 bytes, depending on `NOT NULL`.

Another note:  If you have both `INDEX(dept_id)` and `INDEX(dept_id, create_time)`, the optimizer may pick the former even though the latter is clearly better.  So drop the former index and keep the latter.

Comment: Thank you for explaining "the mysterious 1" and the link to your article.

Comment: @cliash - Thanks.  I occasionally update my blogs.  If you can point out what was difficult to understand, I may be able to think of a better way to phrase it or a better example.

Comment: No, it’s not that your article is not well expressed, it’s just that my English is not very good, so some places are a little difficult to read, and the other reason is that I haven’t touched some related concepts yet :D